# How do you delete a discord channel with a bot. PYTHON

Tags: python, discord

i have looked everywhere for the code but can find it
I've used this but it did not work:

```
await client.delete_channel()
```

anyone know how?

Comment: _I’ve used this but it did not work_ Can you share a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coroutine you're looking for is [`GuildChannel.delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.delete).  It can be applied to any of the types that inherit from `GuildChannel`: `TextChannel`, `VoiceChannel`, and `CategoryChannel`